# Why am I getting an NSRangeException while inserting the 6th element into a tableview?

Tags: iphone, cocoa-touch, uitableview, nsmutablearray

I am inserting data into table view as shown below. There is no problem for 5 to 6 elements if there have more than 6 then App Crashes and shows the error :

`"Terminating app due to uncaught exception 'NSRangeException', reason: '*** -[NSMutableArray objectAtIndex:]: index 11 beyond bounds [0 .. 10]' "`

```
- (NSInteger)tableView:(UITableView *)table numberOfRowsInSection:(NSInteger)section
{
    return [ProductArray count];
}
- (UITableViewCell *)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath;
{
    static NSString *CellIdentifier = @"Cell";
    UITableViewCell *cell = [tableView dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:CellIdentifier];
    if (cell == nil) 
    {
        cell = [[[UITableViewCell alloc] initWithStyle:UITableViewCellStyleDefault reuseIdentifier:CellIdentifier] autorelease];

    }

       NSDictionary *aDict = [ProductArray objectAtIndex:indexPath.row];    
      cell.textLabel.text= [aDict objectForKey:@"ProductName"];


    return cell;
}
```

Comment: Can you post the code with which you insert new data?

Comment: It crashed at more than 6 elements because that is when the table is scrollable. UITableView loads the row when they are scrolled to.

Answer (score 1):

use this code

```
if(indexPath.row < [ProductArray count]){

NSDictionary *aDict = [ProductArray objectAtIndex:indexPath.row];
cell.textLabel.text= [aDict objectForKey:@"ProductName"];

}
```

Answer (score 0):

Clearly the crash message suggests that you are trying to access an element which goes past the limit of elements the array can contain. Pls check if you are updating the numberOfRows in your tableview and the array.

Answer (score 0):

In `numberOfRowsInSection` you must set the correct number for the amount of rows oldNumberOfRows+addedRowsNumber.

Edit:

And in ProductArray add the dictionaryes for each row before you add the rows to the tableview.

Answer (score 0):

The error suggests that you are trying to access an object with index of 11 (12th object) or later in your NSMutableArray that only holds 11 objects. Array indices start at 0 so that might be the problem. Try to do an NSLog on the ProductArray's size and check how many objects it holds. As many have stated before the part that crashes is probably the numberofRowsInSection method. If you don't want to bother with the ProductArray size, just return a fixed number to see if the rest of the code is fine.